# Get most active product on home page in magento 1.8?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

How to get the **most active product (magento 1.8)** on home page basis of following point .

```
1.A review is added or changed for that Product.
2.A comment is added to the review for that Product.
3.A Like is added for that Product(facebook like).
4.A Purchase is made for that Product
5.Product is added to Wishlist.
6.Product Price is changed.
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: Thanks for reapply .I am new in magento so no try yet ! But if you have any solution so share with me Thanks in advance !

Comment: what amount of product you think your catalog will have ?

Comment: 24 product catalog will have !

Answer (score 0):

In case of showing Most Active Products based on points listed by you is not available by default in Magento. There is a paid extension for it. Please go through - 
http://store.belvg.com/facebook-all-in-one.html